# Access class from inside .jar file through java

Tags: java, file, jar

I have a folder of .jar files on my desktop. I want my program to be able to access the class files in the jars and create instances of them. How do I do this?

Edit: The jars are added by the user of my program. I know what folder they are in, and can figure out their names.

Comment: Add the jars as dependencies?

Comment: Are the classes public? Are you the owner of the .jar files?

Comment: The classes I need to access should be public, the jars are meant to be added by users of the program, so they can't be dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Include the JAR in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Include the jar on the classpath:

java -classpath [PATH_TO_JAR] YOUR_CLASS

And on your classes import the classes you wish to use:

import package.CLASS_2_USE_1
Import package.CLASS_2_USE_2

This assuming the classes are public.

Edit: If you want to load classes form jars supplied at runtime it's probably a good idea to agree on a fixed set of methods and class names. You can see how to do it on this thread:

[How should I load Jars dynamically at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime)